# Got incorrect audio duration from ffmpeg

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I used an ffmpeg command to export parts of an audio clip:

```
ffmpeg -i {path} -acodec copy -ss {start_time} -to {end_time} {output_path}
```

Unfortunately, this has the side effect of not changing the time duration in the file's details section, making many programs I use think the time of the cut audio files is much more than it really is.

Is there a way to either make ffmpeg change the duration, or find a command in python that can change an audio file's "length" stat so I can do it manually? I couldn't find any way online.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the duration simply the end_time - start_time?

Comment: Yeah, I really don't know how that didn't enter my head. But in any case I couldn't find any way online to actually change the duration so I'll edit the question to fit that.

Comment: How to edit it in the actual file I'd presume boils down to the file format (not sure what it is, MPEG?  ...and which ver?); ya could cheat/hack by using a hex editor.  Good luck.  :-)

Comment: hex editor? MPEG? I just wanted a Zelda OST playlist... In any case, I'm using flac, not sure if that helps. I'll look up what a hex editor is, but I can guess by the name.

Comment: -t duration in the output?  (see https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis).  anyway, it looks like a bug, the durtion should get updated IMHO--maybe https://www.ffmpeg.org/ can/should help.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529880/ffmpeg-is-not-writing-the-correct-video-duration-in-the-output-playlist-file-for

Comment: It seems I have a very slightly older version of ffmpeg. I'll try to update first, as that's what the problem was with the person in the link you sent.

Comment: Updated to a version published today. Tried both the -ss -to and the -ss -t versions. both of them give me a huge time duration. Any tips?...

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from the log from the ffmpeg command.